# Deriving of the y-coordinate on secp256k1 elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptocurrency

```
slope (s) = 75359724952757581356787150982223137069297282952438962440225639443485944634025
Qx = 112711660439710606056748659173929673102114977341539408544630613555209775888121
Qy = 25583027980570883691656905877401976406448868254816295069919888960541586679410
```

**Derived x and y-coordinate from performing point doubling using the above values**

Using the below formula;

```
s = (3 * Qx**2) * pow(2 * Qy, -1, p) % p 
Rx = (s**2 - 2 * Qx) % p
Ry = (s * (Qx - Rx) - Qy) % p
```

```
Rx = 115780575977492633039504758427830329241728645270042306223540962614150928364886
Ry = 78735063515800386211891312544505775871260717697865196436804966483607426560663
```

**Secp256k1 elliptic curve perameters**

```
Gx = 55066263022277343669578718895168534326250603453777594175500187360389116729240
Gy = 32670510020758816978083085130507043184471273380659243275938904335757337482424
p = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
```

The above **Rx** and **Ry** vairables is derived from `slope (s)`, `Qx` and `Qy` by performing point doubling on elliptic curve and all the vairables provided above are valid points on the curve.

Is there any formula that can be used to derive `Ry` base solely on the `slope (s)`, `Gx`, `Gy`, `p` and `Rx`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you convert this question into something that makes no sense as a question? Besides,in SO, if the answer is find useful for you you can upvote and satisfies your question then you can accept it so that other may find that the answer is correct and useful. This is the way this community works.

Answer (score 2):

Given $Q = (Q_x, Q_y)$ the doubling formula under the condition that $Q_y \neq 0$

\begin{align}
s & =\frac{3 Q_x^2+a}{2Q_y} &(1)\\
R_x & = s^2 -2 Q_x  \mod p & (2)\\
R_y & = s\cdot (Q_x-R_x) -Q_y \mod p & (3)
\end{align}

So, basically asking;

- given $s, G_x, G_y, p$, and $R_x$ **find** $R_y$;

Then, can we find the $R_y$? let see..

1. Find $Q_x$ using (2)

$$
\color{red}{Q_x} = -\frac{R_x - s^2}{2}   \mod p
$$

2. Use this in (1)

   $$s = \frac{3 \color{red}{Q_x}^2+a}{2Q_y}$$

   to get $Q_y$

   $$\color{blue}{Q_y} = \frac{3 \color{red}{Q_x}^2+a}{2s}$$
3. Use (3) to get $R_y$

   $$R_y = s \cdot (\color{red}{Q_x}-R_x) -\color{blue}{Q_y} \mod p,$$

   where we know $p, s, R_x, Q_x$, and $Q_y$ so that we can find $R_y$